# Expression to a C++ class type converter / type cast

Tags: c++

Using MS Visual Studio C++, version 15.9.11, in Windows 10. Why doesn't the line as shown in the code below compile? My suspicion is that it is a compiler bug. Thanks.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C
{
    int foo();
    operator int() { return 1; };
};

// Using the C class inline
using C_foo_t = decltype( std::declval<C>().foo() );
using C_operator_int_t = decltype( std::declval<C>().operator int() );

static_assert( std::is_same< int, C_foo_t >::value, "");; // Ok
static_assert( std::is_same< int, C_operator_int_t >::value, ""); // Ok

// Through a template
template <typename T>
using foo_t = decltype( std::declval<T>().foo() );

template <typename T>
using operator_int_t = decltype( std::declval<T>().operator int() );

static_assert( std::is_same< int, foo_t<C> >::value, ""); // Ok
static_assert( std::is_same< int, operator_int_t<C> >::value, ""); // error C2057: expected constant expression

int main() { return 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for such speedy reply!!.Have you tried it using VS C++ 2017?

Comment: That's settles it. It is a MS C++ Visual Studio compiler bug!!
I have spent hours to find the problem!!
I had trouble in reporting this to MS, I could not log in through the VS Help menu.

Comment: Any work arounds?

Comment: Tried it on VS 2017 and it works. Thank you very much. I can only up vote you once, should be more!! :)

Comment: Given that the comment session became a mess, I decided to delete my comments and make a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All credits to @Curiously for finding a work around to this MSVC compiler bug.
The following is a more simplified form of his solution.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C
{
    operator int();
};

#ifndef _MSC_VER 
// This is the C++11 compliant compiler solution
// MSVC C++ VC2017 -> VC2019 : error C2057: expected constant expression
template <typename T>
using operator_int_t = decltype( std::declval<T>().operator int() );
#else
// Work around for  MSVC VC2017 -> VC2019 compiler bug
template <typename T>
decltype( std::declval<T>().operator int() ) operator_int_helper_t();

template <typename T>
using operator_int_t = decltype( operator_int_helper_t<T>() );

#endif

static_assert( std::is_same< int, operator_int_t<C> >::value, "");


int main() { return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried OP's code both on gcc 9.1 and clang 8.0 (https://godbolt.org/z/N5FMOe for gcc, use the dropdown for clang, the arguments are the same): the code compiles with no issues. MSVC 19.21 (https://godbolt.org/z/h7S_wu) has the aforementioned issue.

I reduced the issue to its bare minimum and I was able to obtain a successful compilation with all 3 compilers (MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/uoifY4, clang/gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/D7zPYu)

```
#include <type_traits>

struct C
{
    int foo();
    operator int() { return 1; };
};

template <typename T>
auto oper_int(const T&) -> decltype( std::declval<T>().operator int() );

template<typename T>
struct  operator_int_t{
    using type = decltype(oper_int(std::declval<T>())); 
};

static_assert( std::is_same< int, operator_int_t<C>::type >::value, ""); // works now

int main() { return 0; }
```

This code, as far as I can tell is equivalent to OP's (granted: this is uglier) but it works on MSVC, I am inclined to think that it is a MSVC bug.